# inputValidator using a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, user-input, jython, jes

I was wanting to understand my code better if there was someone with python/jython knowledge, would love to listen.

This is my code (see below). 
My outcome was to achieve a loop and keep the program running rather than restart the program every time the wrong input was entered by user.

The program now loops successfully but only displays the error message after the correct input has been entered, can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance :)

```
def inputValidator():

while True:
num = requestInteger("Please give me a number between 50 and 112") 

if num > 50 and num < 112:
 print "Successful Login" 
 break
elif num < 50: 
 print "Error! Please input a number more than 50 you entered", num
elif num > 112:
  print "Error! Please input a number less than 112 you entered", num
```

Comment: Please edit your Q to have the correct indents -- it's unreadable as it stands!

Comment: Sorry if I have said or added anything which isn't protocol, this is my first question to stackoverflow, so apologies in advance for "noobiness" heh.

Comment: Nothing about protocol, it's that the **indentation** is all broken -- **please** edit your Q to fix it!!!

Comment: Sorry that wasn't a direct reply to you Alex, the indentation has been changed to be more readable and should make logical sense.

Answer (score 1):

So if I am understanding your question correctly, I assume you are just trying to get a user to input a number between 50 and 112?

It should look something like this, and indentation is very important!

```
def inputValidator():
    while True:
        try:
            number=int(raw_input("Enter a number between 50 and 112! >>> "))  ## Makes input an integer 
            if (number > 50) and (number < 112):   ## Checks if number is between 50 and 112
                print "Number accepted!"
                break
            else: 
                continue
        except:
            print "Please enter a number!"
    return number         ## Returns input number
```

Also, I am unsure if you know about "try" statements, but it just prevents the program from crashing. And you can also change around the text to make it look better! Hope this helps! :)

PS: I presume you just copied and pasted that code, so for future reference, use "Ctrl+K" to correctly and easily format it or just 4+ spaces! ;)